# Is it a way to reference a .NET 7 nuget library in a .NET Standard 2 Library?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to build a library, which target framework is `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>`. However, the library needs to reference a nuget package which depends on .NET 7 only (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Orleans.Core/7.2.4?_src=template).

Comment: As far as I know, no. Is there no `Standard` target for that package?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Cross-platform targeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting?source=recommendations) and [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0#when-to-target-net80-vs-netstandard).

Comment: In short - no, only vice versa. You might want to try earlier versions, like [3.7.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Orleans.Core/3.7.1) which supports .NET Standard. Or go with [multitargeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/multiple-target-frameworks-project-file) and use conditional compilation/package references in your library, see [Adding a PackageReference condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition)

Comment: Multitargeting `net462` and `net6`, and don't waste any time on .NET Standard which is going away.

Answer (score 3):

No, as .NET 7 includes APIs that are not in .NET Standard 2.1.

However I checked the versioning for `Microsoft.Orleans.Core` and [v3.7.1](https://%20https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Orleans.Core/3.7.1#supportedframeworks-body-tab) of the library *does* support .NET Standard 2.1. If you don't need the latest version, use `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Orleans.Core" Version="3.7.1" />`.

As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting):

> Targeting .NET Standard lets you produce libraries that are constrained to use APIs that are in a given version of .NET Standard, which means it's usable by all platforms that implement that version of .NET Standard.

If this was allowed, you'd break the cross-platform support 'guarantee' (at compile time anyway).

Comment: I may have to use Orleans v3.7.1. BTW, for the version of C# .Net standard 2.1, I use `<LangVersion>11</LangVersion>` in the project file.